# PHP email display error

Tags: php, email

Please anyone refer this code and correct it for me. 
I have used this code in another webpage it is working, but now this script is not sending the message, it show my custom error message.

Could you please any one help me to find the problem

Thank you

```
   <?php

        /* for admin */
        $registration_subject="Live demo registration";
        $registration_office="info@xxx.com";

        /* REGISTER details */

        $bizname = $_POST['txtbizname'];
        $biztype = $_POST['cbobiztype'];
        $address = $_POST['TxtAddress'];
        $city = $_POST['TxtCity'];
        $country = $_POST['cboCountry'];
        $tel = $_POST['TxtTel'];
        $fax = $_POST['TxtFax'];
        $email = $_POST['TxtEmail'];
        $web = $_POST['TxtWeb'];    
        $title = $_POST['Cbotitle'];
        $contname = $_POST['txtcontname'];
        $designation = $_POST['TxtDesignation'];
        $mob = $_POST['TxtMob'];
        $contemail = $_POST['TxtcontEmail'];
        $callbiztime = $_POST['BizGMT'];


        $body = <<<EOD
    Business Name : $bizname <br>
    Business Type : $biztype <br>
    Address : $address <br>
    City : $city <br>
    Country : $country <br>
    Tel : $tel <br>
    Fax : $fax <br>
    Email : $email <br>
    Web : $web <br>
    Title : $title <br>
    Contact Person Name : $contname <br>
    Designation : $designation <br>
    Mobile : $mob <br>
    Email : $contemail <br>
    Call Me at : $callbiztime <br>

    EOD;


        $headers = "From : $email\r\n";
        $headers = "Content-type:text/html\r\n";
        $mail_status = mail($registration_office, $registration_subject, $body, $headers);

    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
            window.location = 'b2b.html';
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@xxx.com');
            windowwindow.location = 'b2b.html';
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It shows the `Message failed. Please, send an ....` message? Or what "custom error message" do you mean?

Comment: Are you testing it on localhost? do you have a SMTP server where you are testing it?

Comment: It's problem with your mailing server , not with code.

Comment: What's the error showing?

Comment: @OP: See Christian's answer below, should do 'er. Use this `$headers .= "Content-type:text/html\r\n";` - Notice the missing **dot**?

Answer (score 1):

You've got:

```
$headers = "From : $email\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type:text/html\r\n";
```

You'll want to concatenate the second line onto the first with:

```
$headers  = "From : $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html\r\n";
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - You need to specify a 'From' address, which will be missing because you're currently replacing it with the 'Content-type' line.

Comment: Yep, that missing (`dot`) will do it. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` **at the top** of your script and check for any error in the page or in your error log. If you still have problems, just post the error you get.

Comment: it displays "The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.xxxx.com/B2BSolution.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Comment: It's a problem with your script (HTTP 500 is sometimes returned when PHP encounters an error).  Check carefully your code and put the error_reporting line at the top of that script, too. Post the errors you see.

Comment: Oh, one thing - if you can't spot the bug, you should post the entire code of B2BSolution.php, so that we can analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

Comment your code and just try with some hardcoded values to check if mailing generally works:

```
mail("test@test.com", "My Subject", "blablabla");
```

If it does not work, you have a problem with your mailserver